# Using PHP in Joomla Template

Tags: php, joomla

I'm developing a site using joomla template. I want to create a registration form & I design it with html in a Joomla Article. For data passing to db I have created a PHP file. But I have a problem in submitting data. I gave form action="php file name" & I save the PHP file in index path. But system is not working. Please tell me where I need to save that PHP file & how to link my joomla article & PHP file ???

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, Your question is rather confusing but; I would recommend you google some basic tutorials on how to make a module / component in Joomla or see if somebody already made something you could use.

Comment: Please don't start writing custom PHP code and injecting it in your article. This is not how Joomla is supposed to work. It's a MVC CMS and uses extensions. You should really look for a **Form** extension

Comment: There are lots of form designer extensions which you can easily use to achieve this. Check out http://fabrikar.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom file upload component and upload your php files. Create a menu item for your component and assign a PHP file to menu you want to show your registration form on and finally at front-end include PHP file in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder inside plugins in main directory.
Name it whatever you like, lets say, "customplugin". Put your form handling file in that.
Give the absolute path of this file in the form action URL.

This should work. Also, kindly check if the form tags are coming correctly in the article.

As others are saying, you are actually not using the Joomla CMS properly, but anything and everything is possible...

> Mistakes are always forgivable, if one has the courage to admit them.
>   -- Bruce Lee